# Render a component after a timeout through pure CSS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm aware that there is a way to achieve the effect of a component being rendered after a given timeout but I would like to do it in pure CSS through transitions. The problem is that when looking at tutorials for using css transitions - you usually have to hover over the element in order to trigger the animation - but in my case - I simply want the element to become visible after 2 seconds from being rendered. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

animation can help :

```css
p {
  opacity:0;
  animation:show 5s 2s forwards;
}
@keyframes show {
  to {opacity:1}
}
```

```html
<p>see me</p>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

> The `animation-fill-mode` CSS property specifies how a CSS animation should apply styles to its target before and after its execution.

Comment: I'm struggling to find the documentation for the `animation` property shorthand you're using - would you be able to show me where I can find it?

Comment: @Ogen you may have a look there : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation . Happy New Year

Answer (score 0):

A simple component is in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jYLEqB). You can simply apply the css animation on opacity.

```js
var SomeComponent = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="myClass">My Component</div>
    );
  }
});
 
React.render(
  <SomeComponent />, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.myClass {
  opacity:0;
  animation:show 2s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes show {
  to {
    opacity:1
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```